# How to create JSON objects Folder name and File Name View

Tags: javascript, python, json, javascript-objects, python-jsonschema

I have a JSON File Like this:

```
{
    "Sheet1": [
        {
            "Folder name": "Folder 1",
            "Filename": "1- Introduction.mp4",
        },
        {
            "Filename": "2- Prerequisites.mp4",
        },
        {
            "Filename": "4- What is React Native.mp4",
        },
        {
            "Folder name": "Folder 2",
            "Filename": "1- Knowledge.mp4",
        },
        {
            "Filename": "2- Exercise.mp4",
        },]
 }
```

How Do I make it like this:

```
{
  "Folder 1": [
           {
            "Filename": "1- Introduction.mp4",
           },
           {
            "Filename": "2- Prerequisites.mp4",
           }
           ],

  "Folder 2": [
           {
            "Filename": "1- Knowledge.mp4",
           },
           {
            "Filename": "2- Exercise.mp4",
           }
           ]
}
```

I have New to JSON but I do Know Python Dictionaries. I Tried to do in Python but unable to do this exact way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot, that is not valid json.  You cannot have a value without a key.  You would have to put the multiple objects in an array `[]`

Comment: @Taplar check now. I need to create the files names objects inside that folder name object untill a new folder name key appears. then add the new file names to this new foldername object.

Comment: Same issue.  You cannot have `key: {},{}` in json.  You have to have `key: [{}, {}]`

Comment: @Taplar Is this okay? How to Do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Taplar, you cannot create object values without keys in JSON. You can use an Array of objects instead.

I'm considering that the folder will always be defined in the first element of the array and the next objects with just a "Filename" key will be inside the previous defined folder. Then, when another folder is found, the next files will be inside the new folder.

With that in mind, you can use this function:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function mapFolderStructure(json) {
    const object = JSON.parse(json);
    const returnObject = {};
    let currentFolder = null;
    
    for (const key in object) {
        returnObject[key] = {};
        for (const item of object[key]) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty('Folder name')) {
                currentFolder = item['Folder name'];
            }
            
            if (currentFolder) {
                if (!returnObject[key][currentFolder]) returnObject[key][currentFolder] = [];
                returnObject[key][currentFolder].push({ Filename: item.Filename });
            }
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(returnObject, null, 4);
}

const inputJson = fs.readFileSync('path/to/input', 'utf8');

const outputJson = mapFolderStructure(inputJson);

fs.writeFileSync('path/to/output', outputJson);
```

Comment: Thanks.This is what I needed.